If I'm raptured will I be immortal?
So when I'm raptured? I will not become immortal? Also, if I have children during millennial reign they will be mortal?

Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help (below). The site requires that questions be scoped to particular views and denominational beliefs. This question needs to be addressed to those who follow the rapture/millenial idea rather than that the return of Jesus Christ heralds the end of time, immediate judgment and eternal glory.

This site does not answer personal questions, so the question needs to be reworded without saying "I" or referring to your own situation.  It also does not represent any Christian view, but provides an objective look at the various existing denominations. ¶A more acceptable question would ask something like "What does [specific denomination] teach will happen to the children of those that are taken by Christ at his return?".

Everyone is immortal, whether they are raptured or not ;-) It's only the physical body that dies, just like other animals.
